# Class with keyval option consisting of lists of keyval pairs

Tags: loops, key-value, class-options

I'm trying to figure out how to write a class that would allow for a key-value option where the key is called `people`, which would take a list of grouped key-value pairs (*e.g.,* `name`, `title`, and `role`) and then process that information and typeset it in a list. The list should be formatted like so if `role` is present:

- `title` `name`, `role`

and like so if the `role` is not present:

- `title` `name`

I know I can do this where I just manually format the data when passing it in as the value, like in the following minimal example, but I'd like to be able to have an interface like this instead:

#### desired interface

```
\documentclass[
  people={
    {title={Doctor},name={John Smith},role={Role}},
    {title={Doctor},name={Jane Smith},role={}}}
]{myclass}
```

#### mwe

##### myclass.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\LoadClass[oneside,letterpaper]{memoir}

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\DeclareStringOption[]{people}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\mypeople}[1]{%
  \begin{itemize}
    \expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter\item\expandafter{#1}
  \end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\makemypage}{%
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlingpage}
    \begin{center}
      \mypeople{\myclass@people}
    \end{center}
  \end{titlingpage}}

\endinput
```

##### myfile.tex

```
\documentclass[people={{Mr. John Smith, Role}, {Mrs. Jane Smith}}]{myclass}

\begin{document}
  \makemypage
\end{document}
```

Is there a good way to write the class file so that it could provide the desired interface instead?

Comment: Should an empty role be treated the same way as if the key wasn't used at all?

Comment: I wouldn't pass such data through the class options. class options are handled also by packages and if you have arbitrary text there this can easily break e.g. if your names  contains accents or similar. And you can easily loose the spaces anyway.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, that's the behavior I'd like.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How would you suggest doing this instead, then? Should the class just provide a command called `\people` or something like that? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Yes, a dedicated macro would be much better suited for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would work (note that for personal preferences I implemented the following using `expkv` and friends; disclaimer: I'm the package author).

It loop over your list and uses another key=value set to parse the keys of a single person. The check whether `role` was present is done by comparing it to `\@empty`, and if it's not empty (`\unless`) we output the `role` (the same is done for `title` to also allow those poor people without a title to be named).

**Class file:**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\LoadClass[oneside,letterpaper]{memoir}

\RequirePackage{expkv-def}

\ekvdefinekeys{myclass/people}
  {
     long store title = \myclass@people@title
    ,long store role  = \myclass@people@role
    ,long store name  = \myclass@people@name
  }
\ekvsetdef\myclass@people@options{myclass/people}
\newcommand*\myclass@people{}% <- WAS MISSING
\newcommand\people[1]{\edef\myclass@people{\unexpanded{#1}}}

\newcommand*\mypeople[1]
  {%
    \unless\ifx\myclass@people\@empty
      \begin{itemize}
        \expandafter\ekvcsvloop\expandafter\mypeople@aux\expandafter{#1}%
      \end{itemize}%
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\mypeople@aux[1]
  {%
    \item
    \begingroup
      \myclass@people@options{#1}%
      \unless\ifx\myclass@people@title\@empty
        \myclass@people@title\space
      \fi
      \myclass@people@name
      \unless\ifx\myclass@people@role\@empty
        , \myclass@people@role
      \fi
    \endgroup
  }

\newcommand{\makemypage}{%
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlingpage}
    \begin{center}
      \mypeople{\myclass@people}
    \end{center}
  \end{titlingpage}}

\endinput
```

**Document:**

```
\documentclass[]{myclass}
\people{
  {title={Doctor},name={John Smith},role={Role}},
  {title={Doctor},name={Jane Smith},role={}}}

\begin{document}
  \makemypage
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Note:**

The above doesn't use class options at all (as it's no longer necessary for this example), you could of course use `kvoptions` for class options, or you use `expkv-opt` and its `\ekvoProcessLocalOptions`.

Comment: Thanks! I have a hopefully quick followup question. I can post a new question if you'd like, but thought I'd ask here first. If I want to define another command, such as `\specialperson`, which would have the same keyval pairs as `\people` as well as some others, and I want this person to show up first in the list, is there a good way to do that? I tried following what you've done here, but I got stuck adding `\item \myclass@specialperson@title\space\myclass@specialperson@name, Special Role` to `\mypeople`. It seems `\specialperson` doesn't get processed unless I do something?

Comment: I posted it as [a followup question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/630237/32888). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The code above was missing an initial value for `\myclass@people`! I edited this in (will also be there for the follow up question).